# How to return the slug created using the spatie sluggable?

Tags: php, laravel, slug

How do I grab/return the Slug that is being created using Spatie Sluggable.
I am using slug as identifier between the two tables and would like to update the slug to both the tables from single controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
Section 1 

 $newbook = new Books;
        $newbook->book_code = $request->input('book_code');
        $newbook->title = $request->input('title');
        $newbook->description = $request->input('description');
        $newbook->category = $request->modal_hidden;
        $newbook->amount = $request->input('amount');
        // $newbook->discount = $request->input('discount');
        $newbook->quantity = $request->input('quantity');

       Section 2 

        // ##############################################################
        if (Input::hasFile('desc_photos')) {
            $files = $request->file('desc_photos');
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                print_r($file->getClientOriginalName());
                $path = public_path('images/bookcover/book_desc/' . $filename);
                Image::make($file->getRealPath())
                    ->resize(800, 600)
                    ->save($path);
                $desc_photo = new BookDescImg;
                $file_replace = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . '-' . $file_replace;
                $desc_photo->slug = $request->input('????????'); // what do I give here
                $desc_photo->image_name = $filename;
                $desc_photo->save();
            }
        }

        

        $newbook->save();
}
```

I would like the grab the slug that will be created in the first section and pass it to the second section.

I am quite not sure how can I achieve it.

I am using [spatie/sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) package, and title as slug field.

As a workaround now I am passing book_code but I find it hard to manage in the go.

Also I have another thought of adding a new table and unique key so that these tables are linked through it.

Answer (score 1):

The slug should be:

```
$slug = str_slug($request->input('title'));
$desc_photo->slug = $slug;
```

But if your book name is not unique and has generated the slug previously, in that case, you have to update the `BookDescImg` Slug section. Because Spatie Sluggable package will add integers at the end of the slug, like 1, 2, 3, 4 .. etc. to make the slug unique

Comment: Thank you for responding. I thought of this option. But I dont think I can apply it to code as there would be similar title for book. Would have to take a look on another alternative. Thanks :)